# divide "content" area into two columns?

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm looking at making the transition from HTML tables to pure CSS layouts. So far, the one thing that eludes me is how to layout a page properly.

I can do:

- header
- left navigation
- content
- footer

So like this:

```
________________________ 
|      Header           |
|_______________________|
| Left |     Content    |
| Nav  |                |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|______|________________|
|     Footer            |
|_______________________|
```

However, on some pages I want to be able to divide the "content" area into something like the following:

```
________________________ 
|      Header           |
|_______________________|
| Left | info | info    |
| Nav  |      |         |
|      |      |         |
|      |      |         |
|      |      |         |
|      |______|_________|
|      | Other info     |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|      |                |
|______|________________|
|     Footer            |
|_______________________|
```

Anyone know how something like this would be done? Or even a nice website that helps with this kind of thing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### first layout preview ([online demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/2700941)):

[image]

**html:**

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="main-wrap">
    <div id="sidebar">Left Nav</div>
    <div id="content-wrap">Content</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

**css:**

```
/* sizes */
#main-wrap > div { min-height: 450px; }


#header,
#footer {
    min-height: 40px;
}

/* layout */
#main-wrap {
    /* overflow to handle inner floating block */
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

#content-wrap {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}
```

#### Second layout preview ([online demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/2700950)):

[image]

**html** is quite similar to first layout, but we include one wrapper to `#content-wrap`:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="main-wrap">
    <div id="sidebar">Left Nav</div>
    <div id="content-wrap">
        <div id="info-wrap">
            <div class="info">small info </div>
            <div class="info">small info</div>
        </div>
        Content
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

**css** is also similar, by the way we added some `css` rules to target new div's:

```
/* sizes */
#main-wrap > div { min-height: 450px; }

#header,
#footer {
    min-height: 40px;
}

.info { min-height: 80px; }

/* layout */
#main-wrap {
    /* overflow to handle inner floating block */
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

#content-wrap {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}

#info-wrap {
    /* overflow to handle inner floating block */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.info {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

**update:** improved styles

Comment: So is the key here to force the sidebar to be an absolute position? That way you can use left float in other areas and it won't conflict?

Comment: @Fittersman i remembered better and simpler (without absolute position) way to handle this markup and updated the answer. In all areas we can use `float` without conflict

Answer (score 2):

Give one of the CSS grid systems a go. This site lists some:[10 Really Outstanding and Useful CSS Grid Systems](http://spyrestudios.com/css-grid-systems/)

Answer (score 2):

http://grids.heroku.com/fluid_grid?column_amount=3

You can add and delete these grids.

Answer (score 2):

For your content div set that a width then create three divs for the info sections.

The top two give a width and make sure they dont exceed the total of the container content.
float one left and the other right.

underneath the divs add:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

The css for that is:

```
.clear {clear:both;}
```

Under the clear will be your third div which will give you that layout you want.

Answer (score -2):

Add another inner table in the content column. Make this table as server (runat="server). Specify the condition in code behind file and make the table visible as false or true. Here my example contains a nested table. And i hide it when i had a specific condition via code behind file on specific events.

**eg:**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table >
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    header</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:50px;">
                    left nav
                </td>
                <td>
                    content

                    <table class="style1" id="innertab" runat="server">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                info</td>
                            <td>
                                info</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                other info</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    footer</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code behind file:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["value"].ToString == ValueType)
            {
                innertab.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: using table layout is a bad example of layout

Comment: So where is the code to make it visible or hide? @fittersman: div idea is better to do your design than table. Use the hiding concept as i mentioned above in the matmuchrapna's code.