# show a page in the right split

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to create a electron app and basically i want to split the window the left side i want to show links and the right side whatever links i click into it show there i think it's just html and css stuf but i'm new in electron that's my code :

```
<style>
   .split {
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .left {
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      width: 25%;
    }

    .right {
      right: 0;
      background-color: red;
      width: 75%;
    }

</style>
<script>
    function test() {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object 
    type="text/html" data="add.html" ></object>';
    }
</script>

<div class="split left">

    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <h2>test </h2> <a href="javascript:test()">Some text.</a>
</div>

<div class="split right">

    <div id="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should really be tagged with `html` & `css`; not `electron`. Does this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10599898/1392578 do pretty much what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bellow is the page accoring your question

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .split {
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding-top: 20px;
            height:100%;
        }

        .left {
            left: 0;
            background-color: #111;
            width: 25%;
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .right {
            right: 0;
            background-color: red;
            width: 75%;
            float: right;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="split">
        <div class="split left">

            <h1>Hi</h1>
            <h2>test </h2> <a href="javascript:test()">Some text.</a>
        </div>

        <div class="split right">

            <div id="content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function test() {
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            p.innerText = "This is the test element text";
           
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = p.innerHTML;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't want to create a element i want to show a full file.html

Comment: yes just I am create p tag .you can create html tag (page) dynamically useing create element function